# mat-icon doesn't get styled

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was following the guide at https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started.
I do manage to display material design elements, but my mat-icon do not get styling.

[This is what i'am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgGr0.png)

[This is what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esYPU.png)

component html:

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>My App</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with menu icon">
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-toolbar-row>

  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <span>Second Line</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon favorite-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with heart icon">
      <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with share icon">
      <mat-icon>share</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Module.ts

```js
import {MatToolbarModule} from "@angular/material/toolbar";
import {MatIconModule} from "@angular/material/icon";
```

styles.css

```css
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to provide more code to us

Comment: I added more code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bram, you need to add the button's import also:

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
```

Comment: Added this in app.module.ts, now I get this: 'MatButtonModule' is declared but its value is never read.

Comment: It's because you need to put the MatButtonModule in the array modules, together with MatIconModule

Comment: Adding the MatButtonModule worked, thank you!

Comment: Can you mark my answer as right? You'll see a green mark bellow of my answer when you click in the upvote button

Answer (score 0):

`<mat-icon>` does not have any styling. They do hownever are often used in buttons:

```html
<button mat-icon-button>
  <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
</button>
<button mat-fab>
  <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
</button>
```